# in android i'm getting IOException in Geocoder

Tags: android

it throw IOException if the network is unavailable or any other I/O problem occurs. It need internet connection to use Geocoder.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   double LATITUDE = 37.42233;
   double LONGITUDE = -122.083;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   TextView myLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mylatitude);
   TextView myLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mylongitude);
   TextView myAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myaddress);

   myLatitude.setText("Latitude: " + String.valueOf(LATITUDE));
   myLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + String.valueOf(LONGITUDE));

   Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

   try {
   List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);

   if(addresses != null) {
   Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
   StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
   for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
   strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
   }
  myAddress.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
  }
 else{
 myAddress.setText("No Address returned!");
 }
 } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
myAddress.setText("Cannot get Address!");//and tell me what is 
}

 }
}
```

anyone has any idea?

I have managed to do it with Emulator 2.1 api 8, but then the reverse geocoding always give an empty result. anyone could confirm my code?

**log cat**

```
      06-03 10:59:24.689: W/System.err(4129):java.io.IOException: Service not Available
                       :at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)

                   :at com.example.gprsonandoff.MainActivity.city(MainActivity.java:74)

                :at com.example.gprsonandoff.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
           :android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

         :at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Comment: please add your logcat for the error

Comment: 06-03 10:59:24.689: W/System.err(4129): java.io.IOException: Service not Available
06-03 10:59:24.689: W/System.err(4129):  at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
06-03 10:59:24.689: W/System.err(4129):  at com.example.gprsonandoff.MainActivity.city(MainActivity.java:74)

Comment: You tried with different coordinates? If the service doesn't find any address for the coordinates it will return null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be a prob faced by many. Check [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009).

You can try using [GeoCoding APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) if using Geocoder doesn't work out even if internet connection is there.

Answer (score 0):

I Reboot My Android Device and Error is gone.